# How to get the extension of a file? PHP command line

Tags: php, csv, terminal, command-line-interface

I'm making a CLI script that mass renames files, however I do not know how to get the extension of a file that I don't know the extension of... Basically the CSV file I have is laid out like so:

```
"New filename", "oldfile",
"New filename", "oldfile"
```

No extension is given on the old file. How would I go about doing this? I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: To clarify, a row looks like: `"foo", "bar"` to rename `bar.ext` to `foo.ext`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) will return an array which includes that information. You're specifically looking for the key 'extension'.

```
<?php
// from http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```